# Script permission error, even with CORS enabled

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, cors

I have an iframe on my page P1 which is hosted on server S1. On runtime, i do `iframe.src=` to load page P2 hosted on server S2 inside the iframe.

I know about CORS and on server S2 for page P2, I've already set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and I can confirm the same on response header when I check it in browser.

Now the page P2 and all it's assets load just file, but the moment I try to access P2's DOM from P1 using `window.frames["iframe"].document`, it throws permission error.

Even though I'm setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on server S2, why am I still unable to access P2's DOM? Is this the way `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is supposed to work?

[image: Request-Response]

Comment: What happens with pre-flight request? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Yeah would be great to see the request/response header sources.

Comment: Well, I'm not using XMLHttpRequest and I'm not sure if I can use it with "iframe.src". But I can confirm that the response header for P2 contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" coming from S2.

Comment: I don’t think CORS can disable the SOP when it comes to window access.

Comment: With CORS setup, couldn't you just download the contents of P2 server side and then write it to P1?

Comment: That will defy the purpose of keeping the files on 2 servers. For now, I've hacked it to work using a server proxy, so that P1 and P2 both appears to be on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PostMessages to set communication between documents. Even if they from different domains.

You can send data through PostMessage. It's limited, but this is better then nothing

Take a look at http://easyxdm.net/wp/ it has good api to work with. Long time ago i have made cross-domain http <-> https ajax requests with that lib.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I need richer control than "PostMessages". I'm seeking full DOM manipulation and I thought "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" should provide me that.

Comment: @coreSOLO if you can change iframed page code then you can make RPC calls through `EasyXDM` and make any DOM manipulations you need. It won't be easy but you will definitely can.

Comment: @coreSOLO with `EasyXDM` i was able to harvest content from all script tags in iframe and send it to main page